# Java. Strange behaviour of string.replaceFirst()

Tags: java, string

I have a "balance" string which contain a dollar sign in front of it.
I would like to amend this sign, so I can convert the sting to double, but my code isn't working.

Here is what I've tried:

```
String balance = "$5.30";
balance = balance.replaceFirst("$", "");
```

It looks like the code doesn't make any difference.
To make it even more weird, the code below does exactly what I need:

```
String balance = "$5.30";
balance = balance.replaceFirst(".", "");
```

Even though I could of just use the 2nd code, I want to understand why does it lead to this result.

Comment: See: Regular Expressions. As the Javadocs state, `replaceFirst()` takes one as the first argument.

Comment: [Converting balances to double isn't such a good idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency).

Comment: @JohnFlatness thank you, I'll read it through

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$` and `.` are a special characters(meta character) in java regex world, you should escape it with backslash in order to treat it as a normal charecter.

```
String balance = "$5.30";
balance = balance.replaceFirst("\\$", "");

String balance = "$5.30";
balance = balance.replaceFirst("\\.", "");
```

Thus :

```
      String balance = "$5.30";
      balance = balance.replaceFirst("\\.", "").replaceFirst("\\$", "");
      System.out.println(balance);
```

Output: 530

Just wanted to add more explanation about `$`and `.` meaning in regex:

1. `$` is used to check if line end follows
2. `.` is used to match any sign

here's a tutorial for [Regex in java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/literals.html)

Comment: The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) is crystal clear: *"Replaces the first substring of this string that matches the given **regular expression** with the given replacement."*

Comment: @VladSpreys please dont just copy it, read about regex in oracle java trails its pretty good for basic regex. and also it'd g8 if you'd accept the answer :)

Comment: I sure will, I can't accept the answer just yet (system limitation), but will within 5 minutes